# Async function en Javascript NodeJS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongoose, async-await

Estoy tratando de actualizar la contraseña de un usuario ya registrado y para ello primero encripto la nueva contraseña y después se la cambio, he tratado de varias formas y solo logro que se bloquee porque no cumple la promesa o devuelva una password null

Esta es la función que llamo con un await:

```
function encriptarNueva(newPassword) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        bcrypt.hash(newPassword, null, null, (err, hash) => {
            resolve = hash;
        });
    });
}
```

Y esta la función para cambiar la contraseña:

```
async function changePassword(req, res) {
    var params = req.body;
    var email = params.email;
    var password = params.password;
    var newPassword = params.newPassword;
    var nuevaPass;
    let userId = req.params.id;
    
    // Evitar que un usuario actualice a otro usuario:
    if (userId != req.user.sub) {
        return res.status(500).send({
            message: 'No tienes permiso para actualizar la contraseña de este usuario'
        });
    }
    
    nuevaPass = await encriptarNueva(newPassword);
    
    User.findOne({email: email}, (err, user) => {
        if (err)
            return res.status(500).send({
                message: 'Error en la petición'
            });
        if (user) {
            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, check) => {
                if (check) {
                    params.password = nuevaPass;
                    User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, params, {new : true}, (err, userUpdated) => {
                        if (err)
                            return res.status(500).send({
                                message: 'Error en la petición de actualizar la contraseña'
                            });
                        if (!userUpdated)
                            return res.status(404).send({
                                message: 'No se ha podido actualizar la contraseña'
                            });
                        return res.status(200).send({user: userUpdated});
                        });
                } else {
                    return res.status(404).send({
                        message: 'La contraseña actual es incorrecta.',
                        user: user.password,
                        newPassword: newPassword,
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            return res.status(404).send({
                message: 'El correo asociado es inexistente'
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Para qué haces que sea una promesa si le vas a poner un `await` delante? La gracia de usar promesas es no tener código síncrono que se quede "*en espera*"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es necesario envolver bcrypt en una promesa puesto que ya regresa una promesa, como lo marca la [documentación](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt#with-promises). Ahora solo queda hacer tu función async y regresar el hash.

```
async function encriptarNueva(newPassword) {
    const hashed= await bcrypt.hash(newPassword, null);
    return hashed;
}
```

Comment: Gracias, he modificado la función de encriptar la password como has dicho, pero al hacer peticiones se me sigue quedando colgado, le he añadido then, catch al await encriptarNueva y se cuelga igual, que es lo que me esta fallando ahí?

Comment: @TrueAlexCv, Pueden ser varias razones, lo ideal es que hagas un **debug** para ver en que punto tu app deja de funcionar, inspecciona que las variables no sean nulas, verifica que este encontrando un usuario, etc. Te dejo una guia sencilla para poder hacer un debug con tu navegador de chrome. [Como hacer un debug de nodejs con chrome](https://medium.com/engie-factory-devteam/c%C3%B3mo-hacer-debug-de-nodejs-con-chrome-66160bf91594)

Answer (score 1):

Los parámetros que reciben las promesas no son variables, son funciones, puedes saber mas acerca de las promesas [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise)

```
function encriptarNueva(newPassword) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        bcrypt.hash(newPassword, null, null, (err, hash) => {
            resolve(hash);
        });
    });
}
```